# Displaying PPT into RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi4

I need to slideshow a PPT(slide by slide) in a RPI, can anyone suggest any python program to display the PPT.

Note:

Tried using "soffice --show ~/sample.pptx --norestore" command - Opens in Slideshow, Doesn't move to the next slide in PPT

Tried "libreoffice --impress sample..ppt" - opens the ppt.

Comment: If you can basically open the file in soffice or libreoffice, the problem is most likely with the ppt (maybe it's using very specific features). Nothing we can fix here.

Comment: @PMF, generally how does people show PPT through RPI in monitor(I mean which packages do they use and how do they do that)

Comment: I do not know how this is "generally" done, but LibreOffice works on the Pi (and is installed by default, I think), so that's probably about your best option

Comment: @PMF, I mean using libre office impress, how can I loop a PPT in RPI using CLI commands

Comment: I do not know. I would first make sure the PPT loops automatically if you start it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display the PPT in RPI, by converting the PPT into PDF, PDF to Images and displayed those images using python script.